# Problem from Bryant's book on combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I haven't found this question to be asked before.
Here is a problem that might seem easy at first glance:

"There are $n$ people in a queue for the cinema (and, being in England, the order of people in the queue never changes).
They are let into the cinema in $k$ batches, each batch consisting of one or more persons.
In how many ways can the k batches be chosen?"

From my own calculations the solution should be: $\dbinom{n-1}{k-1}$ where $n$ is the number of people in the queue.

Could someone help me find out the general pattern arising in this problem,
and/or correct my own solution(which may be incorrect)?

Comment: I think this is the [composition of a number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29).

Comment: This is one of the usual Stars and Bars variants, we choose $k-1$ "gaps" between people to insert separators.  Your answer is correct.

Comment: @Masacroso:  It would be compositions if $k$ were variable. I would interpret the wording as meaning $k$ is fixed, but one could have other interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

André Nicolas gave the answer in a comment.

If you create $k$ batches by inserting $k-1$ separators into the queue  by giving the last person in a batch a separator, you should not give one to the last person in the queue.  So you have $n-1$ people to give $k-1$ separators to, and so have ${n-1 \choose k-1}$ possible ways of doing this.